# How to createElement blade component in Laravel + Javascript?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a component called `<x-form.base-form-input/>`. I am trying to make a new base form input element when button onClick.

The problem I'm facing is when calling `createElement()`, I must specify the tag name, so my blade component will be the child of that tag. Therefore, I'm unable to `removeChild()`.

Are there any way I can define the new Element by my blade component or making an "abstract" element?

Here's my JS in the blade view:

```
if (getClickedRadio) {
            let newEl = document.createElement('div');
            newEl.innerHTML = `
                <x-form.base-form-input title="Nama Perusahaan" type="text" name="organizer_name" id="organizer_name" :label="true">
                    @error('organizer_name')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                    @enderror
                </x-form.base-form-input>
            `
            rolesEl.appendChild(newEl);
        }
```

Comment: I am not so sure if I understand this questions correctly, are you looking to create a blade component like this `let bladeComponent = document.createElement('x-form.base-form-input');`? Can you elaborate as to what's the problem? Finding it difficult to understand `The problem I'm facing is when calling createElement(), I must specify the tag name, so my blade component will be the child of that tag. Therefore, I'm unable to removeChild().`

Comment: Oh I think I missed something in my question. You're kinda right. I'm trying to append my base-form-input component to an existing div element child, with props as above.